# MySQL Join Query By Multiple ID In Single Cell

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have following data (sample) for template table

```
TempName, ItemID
Test1, 1/5/6/8/11
Test2, 2/4/5/8/10
```

So, i like to make a sql query that will join with Item Tables And Return All the rows of data that matched/exists in ItemID Field

Something like:
Select * From Items Inner Join Template On Items.ID = Template.ItemID Where Template Name = 'Test1';

i can't figure correct sql query so, now i am using a for loop and but i prefer one liner or better query/script to handle that.

currently my code is like:

```
Select ItemID From Template Where Name = 'Test1';
$strItems = explode('/', ItemID)
foreach($strItem in $strItems)
{
 select * from Items where ID = $strItem
}
```

that's not the pretty/well formatted code, but to show how i am working now..
but i am looking for a better approach :)

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `FIND_IN_SET` here, with a single query:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Items i
INNER JOIN Template t
    ON FIND_IN_SET(i.ID, REPLACE(t.ItemID, '/', ',')) > 0
WHERE
    t.Name = 'Test1';
```

### Demo

But note that storing unnormalized data as you have done in the `Template` table is not idea at all.  It would be much better to store the `ItemID` values across separate rows.

Comment: Bigeleisen, but sir, in that case i will have so many rows on template table where  all row will have same "Name" value. doesn't it look odd?

Comment: Not at all.  Actually, yes, it looks odd, and that's because you shouldn't be repeating the template names there either.  Instead, have some `template_id` value and use that, then have another table which relates `template_id` to actual template name.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my another idea/logic is to not create unnecessary table if really don't need. by the way, this not relates to this question.. and your answer is awesome. thanks again.

Comment: You're right about not creating an unnecessary table, but if required to _normalize_ your data, then such a table certainly is not unnecessary.